# no argument props method does not get called from child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and js I need some clarifications on binding of methods in components

I have 2 components ParentComponent and ChildComponent

**Parent**

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({

methodArg: function (value) {
    console.log("methodArg called", value);
},

methodNoArg: function () {
    console.log("methodNoArg called");
},

render: function () {
    return <ChildComponent m1={(value) => this.methodArg(value)} m2={() => this.methodNoArg} />
}

})
```

**Child**

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={()=>this.props.m1(100)}>Call M1</button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.props.m2()}>Call M2</button>
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

When i click **Call M1** button, **methodArg()** of parent is getting called.

But when I click **Call M2** **methodNoArg()** is not getting called. What is the issue in this ?

When I pass **methodNoArg** to Child , it is getting called

```
 <ChildComponent m1={this.methodArg()} m2={this.methodNoArg} />
```

But **methodArg()** is getting called without clicking the button , its getting called everytime when the child component is rendered.

Comment: you are missing `()` after `this.methodNoArg` - `this.methodNoArg` returns pointer to `function`, you still have to invoke it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.m1(100)}>Call M1</button>
```

Your above line is saying evaluate the m1 method and assign the result to onClick. So when you refresh your page you console.log statement with value you passed gets printed but it will never gets called again no matter how many times you click the button as onClick now does not have method assigned to it now.

You can achieve what you want by removing that parenthesis which is calling the method automatically without clicking.

Here is working jsfiddle code link :
http://jsfiddle.net/fp0LvkLg/

Comment: arrow function is just a way of binding . {this.props.m1.bind(this,100)} is same as {()=>this.props.m1(100)}. in your jsfiddle code. try removing bind and check. the method m1 will be called before the button is clicked.
<button type="submit" onClick={this.props.m1(100)}>Call1</button>

Comment: you are right, there is negligible difference between arrow and bind except you cant use arrow with new n few more. But in your above jsfiddle you are not binding if i am checking properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way you assign your method to a prop

`m2={() => this.methodNoArg}`

is (kind of if we omit the intricacies of `this`) equivalent to

`m2={function() {return this.methodNoArg}}`

So your prop is a function, which returns a function, which in turn is never called.

You want to simply assign your function to a prop like this:

`m2={this.methodNoArg}`

Comment: but I am calling the method m2  like this in child right this.props.m2(). Which is method invocation ?.

Comment: you mean there is a function of a function which returns only method object.
If i call this.props.m2() it returns this.methodNoArg, but doesnot call methodNoArg ?

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening

Comment: Great, Your are right.. when I call the method like this this.props.m2()(), it is invoking the method methodNoArg. I need one more favour , what causes my other method "methodArg" to be invoked every time child component renders ?